# UpdatePanel does not work after publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, publish

I have website (C#, ASP.NET, .NET 4.0) and using ASP.NET Ajax (Update Panel) and jQuery Ajax.

On client side, everything is ok and there is no any error...

After publish the website on the host, jQuery ajax work fine but update panel does not work and make postback and page refresh!

the .NET setting of host is .NET 4.0 too.

i dont know where is the problem and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error on client was:

SCRIPT5022: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.

SCRIPT5009: 'Sys' is undefined

After many time to mining the websites, and more solutions, i solve the problem:

**the solution for .NET 4.0 is:**

Set EnableCdn property of script manager to true :)
Like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableCdn="true">
```

**Next Solution and Better Solution is:**

add this handler to your web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check whether all the ajax libraries are copied to the publish folder

Comment: the jQuery Ajax Load successfuly, but asp.net ajax dosent work.

Comment: i got this error when debug with developer tools:

SCRIPT5022: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load. 
OfficeSearch.aspx, line 62 character 34
SCRIPT5009: 'Sys' is undefined 
OfficeSearch.aspx, line 142 character 1